# Table with spans over multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for solution method to visualize something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMmB4.png). It should be a table where spans can go over multiple columns.
One should also be able to drag&drop these spans. These spans should reorder themselves correct.

I am not necessarily looking for a code solution, just the solution idea I should proceed with.

Answer (score 0):

This looks mostly likely styling, CSS or Cascading Style Sheets.  To achieve what you're looking for can be done pretty easily with Bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com/ . But there are tons of CSS libraries you can use.  It's really your preference and how custom you want.

You can also look on GitHub for similar solutions.  These solutions show code examples and can give you even more insight on what you may or may not want to do.

Good luck to you

Comment: On Bootstrap you'll want to look at the grid layouts.  You could/can define a calendar within the body and overlay the grid.  Could take some playing around.  Codepen also has plenty of CSS like projects you can observe as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: relative` to the all `td's` of the table and then `position: absolute` and a `z-index` bigger than the `td's` to the `span's`, so the spans will be drawn over your `td's`